# Updating site with real-time counter input

Tags: javascript, real-time

Whats the best way to update a site with manual changes?

I have a very basic number counter and want to update it in real time when I change it.

I eventually am going to scrape the site of this dynamic data and if you have any ideas on that, Id really appreciate it. Thank you

Comment: I suggest using Web sockets or server push

Comment: @Moogs, which would be better for scraping the data afterwords. Which brings up another question. How would I scrape the data? Also, What type of server would I need? Thanks

Comment: If you're using Node.js I really like cheerio https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio